# Catch non-standard output from .jar file

Tags: c#, java, user-interface, jar, minecraft

I'm trying to make a GUI for hosting Minecraft CraftBukkit servers in C#. CraftBukkit servers are hosted with a .jar which's source code can be found here: https://github.com/Bukkit/CraftBukkit/.

So far I am able to receive output from it and give input to it like this:

```
var serverProcInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("javaw",
                                                  "-jar -Xms" + Ram + "M -Xmx" + Ram + "M \"" +
                                                  JarFileLocation + "\" -nojline " + AdditionalParams)
            {
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                UseShellExecute = false
            };

        serverProc = new Process {StartInfo = serverProcInfo };

        serverProc.OutputDataReceived += ServerOutputDataReceived;
        serverProc.ErrorDataReceived += ServerOutputDataReceived;

        serverProc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        serverProc.BeginErrorReadLine();
        serverProc.WaitForExit();
```

**I want to create a list of all the players that are currently online.**

When a player joins a message like this is outputed `player < playername > has joined the server`. I know that I could split this string and get the player name, but I think that it is not very good since somebody may say something like that in chat, and my program could interpret it as if somebody joined the server.

I saw other programs do this ("BukkitGUI"), but I'm not sure how I could do this. **Does the .jar file output the player list? What should I look for in its source code to see what it outputs?**

I am relatively new to C# and have never learned Java. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT1:**
I found that the CraftBukkit.jar has a class like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Player[] getOnlinePlayers() {
    List<EntityPlayer> online = playerList.players;
    Player[] players = new Player[online.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
        players[i] = online.get(i).playerConnection.getPlayer();
    }
    return players;
}
```

Is there any way I can call this class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution to this. It is actually quite easy.

First I create a process that will start the .jar file. Then I do the following:

```
Process.OutputDataReceived += ServerOutputHandler.ServerOutputReceived;
Process.ErrorDataReceived += ServerOutputHandler.ServerOutputReceived;
```

and after I start the process (`Process.Start`):

```
Process.BeginOutputReadLine();
Process.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

If you want to know more about handling .jar files, feel free to take a look at my open source project (I gave up it a while ago) [ServerCrafter](https://servercrafter.codeplex.com/). For the part of the source code where I do code I mention above, take a look here: [Server Crafter source code: ServerCrafter\ServerCrafter.ClassLibrary\ClassLibrary\Server\Server.cs](https://servercrafter.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#ServerCrafter/ServerCrafter.ClassLibrary/ClassLibrary/Server/Server.cs)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately cross-process communication between java and C# is not so simple. Your best bet is to either send the list command to the server and parse the output, or if you're willing to write some java you could create a plugin for the minecraft server that opens a socket and send information back and forth.

Comment: Yeah, sadly that is the only way, but thank you for your answer.